# How to receive the API response in case 403 forbiddein using RestTemplate in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, resttemplate

I have a function that calls an external API using RestTemplate.

```
public ApiResponse callApi(String url, ApiRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<ApiRequest> httpRequest = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, httpRequest, ApiResponse.class);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

It works fine in the case of HTTP code 200 but throws an exception in the case of 403 code. However, even in case of 403 forbidden error, I still want to know the message in the response body which I am receiving.

This is the response body of the API which comes with 403 response when hit with Postman, also gets logged the same in exception stack trace when hit with the code:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "Invalid key",
    "errorcode": "A002",
    "data": null
}
```

This is the structure of ApiResponse:

```
public class ApiResponse {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private String errorcode;
}
```

What should I do to extract the body of the response?

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the exception thrown by RestTemplate, by default it gonna throw `HttpStatusCodeException` :

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, httpRequest, ApiResponse.class);      
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    log.warn(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

and try to use a `controlleradvice` to map the exception